# chrome Back-forward Cache disable because App Banner was present upon navigating away

Tags: google-chrome, navigation, bfcache

chrome Back-forward Cache disable because App Banner was present upon navigating away.

EmbedderAppBannerManager

when I remove manifest.json its work fine

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think we cannot do anyting, because "Pending Support. Chrome doesn't support these features yet, so they prevent caching. However, once supported, Chrome removes these limitations."
The current solution is remove service-worker, it confirmed by smasing-magazine https://twitter.com/yoavweiss/status/1501823138786594820

[image]